# Why isn't the arrayformula applying to the entire column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have the following formula in cell D2 of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yUS6Tm0RYLtSPeNoPQ4WGuDRDdZk3MiI7w5pWu_rnpc/edit?usp=sharing). The formula itself is in an "arrayformula" and the formula itself works, but it isn't automatically applying to the entire column - I have to manually paste the formula in order for it to work in each cell of the column even though it has the arrayformula in it. How could I fix this?

Here is the formula that I've used:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF('RAW ACTIVITY LOGS IMPORTED'!$C$2:$C,A2,'RAW ACTIVITY LOGS IMPORTED'!$F$2:$F))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY('RAW ACTIVITY LOGS IMPORTED'!C2:F, 
 "select C,sum(F) group by C label sum(F)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Just curious to know, what was the difference between my function and yours?

Comment: @ReggyB for starters you used in your formula a cell reference A2 so arrayformula wrapping has no sense because it will always look for A2 only not continuing down the column